# How to remove extra rows and columns with NA values when importing from csv file using R

Tags: r, csv, na

I have just started learning R. I'm trying to input data from a .csv file and but R keeps adding extra rows and columns with NA values. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Any advice on removing these NA would be greatly appreciated.  I have used the following code:

```
>no_col <- max(count.fields("6%AA_comp.csv", sep=","))
>mydata <- read.csv(file="6%AA_comp.csv", fill=TRUE, header=TRUE, col.names = 1:no_col-1)
>mydata

X0     X1     X2     X3 X4
1  206428 152160 122080 111940 NA
2  183620 148300 118820 107260 NA
3  169100 164480 151420 146200 NA
4  179000 135920 107340  93540 NA
5  213820 146640 113040 109140 NA
6  150920 141400 133600 132000 NA
7  185645 154000 124510 128900 NA
8  176102 139100 141000 110300 NA
9  159045 154350 121050 153500 NA
10 198610 161000 119000 105600 NA
11 183100 138900 141500 129550 NA
12 211050 142550 136700 113500 NA
13 167000 150100 120000 102540 NA
14     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
15     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
16     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
```

Comment: Why are you doing the `no_col`-route? Does just doing `read.csv` not get you the needed results?

Comment: In my experience, this often has to do with the input file's data formatting. You could handle this with pre or post processing.

Comment: PS `1:no_col-1` isn't very readable in my opinion. I'd use `(1:no_col)-1` instead

Comment: And you use header =T, so why the need to set colnames?

Comment: How many lines your CSV-file has? (inclusive empty lines)

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Was trying the no_col route in attempt to get rid of the NA values. I've now fixed the problem using indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, data cleansing is always half the job or more. What you can do is to read the file as it is and then clean it by indexing only the rows and columns you are interested in, in your case this would be:

```
mydata <- read.csv(file="6%AA_comp.csv", fill=TRUE, header=TRUE)
mydata <- mydata[1:13, 1:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you delete some rows from your csv file and then try and import the same.

If its a one off, the easiest solution will be to open the csv in excel and delete all the rows below the last data row.

Addressing the comment below, we can do something like this

```
    NA.Count = function(x)
    {
        return(sum(is.na(x)))
    }

Row.NA.Count = apply(MAT,1,NA.Count)

Idx = Row.NA.Count == ncol(MAT)

MAT = MAT[!Idx,]
```

where MAT is the imported matrix.

The above code will take care of all the empty rows. You can do a similar thing for the columns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How exactly would you delete empty rows though?